# package name of OneDrive and InsiderHub in Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10

Could you please help to find out the package name of OneDrive and InsiderHub in Windows 10 OS.

Thanks,

Bilaal John

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName
```

Comment: Got the insider hub details but not able to find packagename of OneDrive

Comment: Look for SkyDrive. As far as i remember OneDrive identifiers are SkyDriver yet.

Answer (score 1):

We will get all package list from 
**Get-AppxPackage | select name, packagefamilyname**.

Here's the output for Insider Hub on my machine:

```css
Microsoft.Windows.FeatureOnDemand.InsiderHub Microsoft.Windows.FeatureOnDemand.InsiderHub_cw5n1h2txyewy
```

**OneDrive** is not a metro app so it is not listed.

The Onedrivesetup app is located in "**C:\Windows\SysWOW64**".

If the main issue is to remove it. We could try to run "**C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe /uninstall**". Double click it to install OneDrive.

Thanks for the support and reply's,
Bilaal John S